# Formating text in Empathy chat

Tags: empathy

I love the look of Empathy so much more than Pidgin and would really like to use it as my main chat client but I can't seem to find a way to format text.

It does not appear to be a feature of the program even though I would assume that being able to bold or italicize words would be a basic need in chat.

Is there a way to do this that I've missed? Or perhaps another program would better suit my needs (not Pidgin unless I can completely overhaul the chat window, that is way too much of a 90s flashback for me)?

Answer (score 0):

Does not Look like formatting of chat messages is possible, it is not listed as one of the features on the [Gnome Empathy page](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Apps/Empathy).  About all I can find is that emoticons (smileys) can be used.